# Custom mode in Brace wrapper for Ace Editor

Tags: angular, ace-editor

I am using Ace Editor with Angular 8: Brace wraps Ace Editor, and the ngx-ace-wrapper wraps Brace for Angular.

It is possible to create a custom mode for Ace Editor with `ace.define()`. However, Ace has a default folder for modes. It appears that this can be customized with a function called `setModuleUrl` in the config, but it doesn't appear to be accessible with the Brace wrapper.

I have tried `setOption()` with options like `$moduleUrls`, `modePath` and others, but these don't appear to be valid configuration options (Ace returns something like: `misspelled option "modePath"`).

I cannot put the custom mode definition file inside the correct directory because it is not part of my module/repository. What is the correct way to do configure a custom mode path in Brace/ngx-ace-wrapper?